# Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component when using touchableopacity

Tags: react-native

This is the code that is giving me this error and I cannot find a solution:

```
{ hasTracked ? null :
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}> 
           <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Track data</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
{!hasTracked &&
    < Pressable style={styles.button}> 
       <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Track data</Text>
    </Pressable >
}
```

Here is an [example](https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/text-within-pressable)

As described [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.66/touchableopacity) the future proof way of handle a touch is a Pressable, it seems to be the future is now.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot! I have previously tried this as well just wrote {hasTracked === false && ...} and didn't work so gave up on this version :'D

Comment: Why should the OP, I , or anyone else "Try this"? Instead, please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score 0):

To Explain the reason you are getting this error, it looks like hasTracked is not always a boolean because as you said `hasTracked === false` wasn't working either.

hasTracked not always being a boolean is the real problem with your code you posted above. Meaning this should also work:

```
{ !!hasTracked ? null :
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}> 
           <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Track data</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
}
```

`!!hasTracked` casts the variable into a boolean. The JSX parser will try to turn anything that is not a boolean into a string thus your error "Text must be rendered in a text component."
The parser is translating has value to something like this:

```
{"undefined" ? null :
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}> 
           <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Track data</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
}
```

Which ends up being parsed as this:

```
"undefined"
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}> 
  <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Track data</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Because of this when I am writing if's in a JSX component I always try to cast to booleans by doing the '!!' or '!' depending on my use case so I don't get caught with this issue.

Typically you see it written like this in react native:

```
{!hasTracked &&
    <Pressable style={styles.button}> 
       <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Track data</Text>
    </Pressable >
}
```

The reason this works is because the single bang(!) is casting the value into a boolean as well.